# How to modify printf with last -10 command in bash

Tags: bash, printf

I have a script in Ubuntu 20.04 that sends an email periodically with some server info, and recently one line is giving me an error:

```
printf "Last logins (last -10) \n"$(last -10)" \n"

output:
Last logins (last -10) 
root     pts/4        192.168.3.120    Mon Mar 20 08:54   still logged in
root     pts/4        192.168.3.120    Mon Mar 20 08:47 - 08:53  (00:06)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-144-generi Mon Mar 20 08:44   still running
bash: printf: ` ': invalid format character
dcn5     pts/9        tmux(7992).
```

So looks like something with displaying string.  If I just do `last -10` I get:

```
root     pts/4        192.168.3.120    Mon Mar 20 08:54   still logged in
root     pts/4        192.168.3.120    Mon Mar 20 08:47 - 08:53  (00:06)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-144-generi Mon Mar 20 08:44   still running
dcn5     pts/9        tmux(7992).%3    Mon Mar 20 08:02 - 08:15  (00:12)
dcn5     pts/8        tmux(7992).%2    Mon Mar 20 08:02 - 08:15  (00:12)
dcn5     pts/7        tmux(7992).%1    Mon Mar 20 08:02 - 08:15  (00:12)
dcn5     pts/6        tmux(7992).%0    Mon Mar 20 08:02 - 08:02  (00:00)
root     pts/4        192.168.3.120    Mon Mar 20 07:51 - down   (00:52)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-144-generi Mon Mar 20 07:50 - 08:44  (00:53)
dcn5     pts/8        tmux(25754).%3   Fri Mar 17 23:14 - 23:34  (00:20)
```

I suspect it could be the `%` to be treated like special character.  Not sure why is it displayed.  In Fedora it never displays it like this.
So how to modify `printf` command not to give an error?

Comment: Please add your desired output in the question.

Comment: Desired output is as it is show in `last -10`

Comment: `echo 'Last logins (last -10)'; last -10`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf` is intended to work as this:

```
printf FORMAT_STRING ARG1 ARG2 ...
```

The format string describes how arguments will be interpolated into the string and how they will get formatted.

Simple example:

```
printf '%s %s!\n' 'hello' 'world'
```

`%s` will be replaced `hello` and `world`, in order. Read more about printf and format strings: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-printf

Important Note: (For some, traditional reason ...) By its signature, passing arguments to `printf` is optional. This allows to more easily use it for constant messages as well (message which don't contain variable content). Like this:

```
printf 'test\n'
```

instead of

```
printf '%s\n' 'test'
```

But when you using only argument, you must make sure your message doesn't contain the format character `%`!

---

About your example. The message to be printed contains `%` chars which are interpreted by `printf` as format characters. You have to use a format string:

```
printf 'Last logins (last -10) \n %s' "$(last -10)"
```

Comment: Thanks @hek2mgl that works  I just added another `\n` after %s.

Comment: Thanks @hek2mgl, on expanding and explanation.  Btw what does the `!` do in your simple example? Or is it a typo?  I get `event not found`

Comment: You get _event not found_ only in an interactive shell (or with history expansion explicitly turned on). In this case, you would have to escape the `!` or turn off history expansion. But using an interactive shell for scripting does not make much sense anyway, so I would research first, why you have enabled history expansion here.

Comment: Thanks @user1934428 I don't quite follow.  So `!` should be displayed as exlamation ater `world` or needs to escape new line?

Comment: If history expansion is turned on, the exclamation mark prefixes the event you want to call up, and the error message says that such event does not exist. Writing `\!` should fix it, but if this were my code, I would first ensure that history expansion is turned off.